# Cannot add a unique_ptr to a std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, std, unique-ptr

After searching through books and online until the onset of a big pain between my ears, I cannot figure out how to add a `std::unique_ptr` to a `std::array`.

The following is a class member:

```
std::array<std::unique_ptr<Media>, MAX_ELMS_NUM> m_collection;
```

In the `.cpp` file I am trying to add a new media pointer stuffed in a `std::unique_ptr` to the array:

```
Media* newMedia = CreateNewMedia(Media info stuff);
unique_ptr<Media> np(newMedia);
m_collection[0] = np;
```

Everything compiles except for the last line.

Comment: Does `m_collection[0] = std::move(np);` work?

Comment: You got to move it baby, you got to move it baby.  Come on and make it all right.

Answer (score 3):

[`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) can't be copied, but moved, because it's *unique*. You could use [`std::move`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move).

> The class (std::unique_ptr) satisfies the requirements of MoveConstructible and MoveAssignable, but not the requirements of either CopyConstructible or CopyAssignable.
>
> std::move is used to indicate that an object t may be "moved from", i.e. allowing the efficient transfer of resources from t to another object.

```
Media* newMedia = CreateNewMedia(Media info stuff);
unique_ptr<Media> np(newMedia);
m_collection[0] = std::move(np);
                  ~~~~~~~~~
```

BTW: As @M.M mentioned, using [`std::unique_ptr::reset`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset) could solve your problem too, and more clear by avoiding all the temporary variables.

```
m_collection[0].reset(CreateNewMedia(Media info stuff));
```

Answer (score 3):

The last line is an attempt to do a copy assignment operation, which is `delete`d for `std::unique_ptr`.  You need to use the move-assignment operator:

```
m_collection[0] = std::move(np);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't copy a `unique_ptr`, full stop. That's what "unique" means - there is only *one* `unique_ptr` pointing to the same object.

Now, you *can* assign a `unique_ptr` to a different one, but that clears the original one. Since it would be *really confusing* if `a = b` modified `b`, you have to specifically indicate that you want this, with `std::move`:

```
m_collection[0] = std::move(np);
```

After this line, `m_collection[0]` will point to the `Media` object, and `np` will be cleared.